# rpush vs sns for large scale push notifications

Tags: ruby, push-notification, amazon-sns

Currently we use Amazon SNS to deliver push notifications to our Android and iOS mobile apps. SNS seems to miss a notification once in a while and there's a particular kind of notification that we can not afford to not deliver. Is there a method that guarantees delivery of every notification while still using SNS? An option I'm considering at the moment is using the [rpush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush) gem, but I would like to know how well it performs as compared to SNS.

The backend is written in Ruby/Sinatra.

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion, @Aayush Kothari

Comment: This post might be useful: https://medium.com/@jplethier/using-amason-sns-to-send-push-notifications-on-rails-projects-c917114472d#.u9m88vrob

Comment: @mooreds Thanks for the suggestion, but we had already tried the same flow as the medium article suggests. We eventually switched to One Signal (https://github.com/tbalthazar/onesignal-ruby). It is pretty amazing in simplicity of integration and the capabilities it provides on the admin dashboard. I could write an essay on how it's leagues ahead of SNS.

Comment: Bummer!  I'm just starting down the path of SNS.  Will have to take a look at One Signal.